# crontab tar archive on macOS not recursive

Tags: macos, symbolic-link, cron, tar

I have a script to archive a directory on macOS:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

BACKUPNAME=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d@%H:%M:%S")
BACKUPNAME="local-vaults-$BACKUPNAME.tar.gz"

tar czfh "/Users/henrik/backups/$BACKUPNAME" "/Users/henrik/vaults"
```

Running the script in the shell works fine, but running it via `cron` the archive only contains the top level directory:

```bash
% tar tvf local-vaults-2023-10-25@12:00:00.tar.gz 
drwxr-xr-x  0 henrik staff       0 Apr 29 02:09 Users/henrik/vaults/
```

The `vaults` path is a symlink: `/Users/henrik/vaults -> /Users/henrik/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~md~obsidian/Documents`, so I tried to replace the source path with the full path, still double-quoted because there's a space between `Mobile` and `Documents`, but this makes no difference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ~/Library/Mobile Documents is a "private" area, which requires special per-application access. Terminal probably has this access, but cron doesn't. See ["What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673) and ["cronjobs do not run"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402132).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, I completely forgot about this. Usually, macOS will pop up a dialog when needed, but `cron` does not run as your user, so not possible in that case. To get `cron` working for this kind of scenario, it needs `full disk access`: System Preferences `>` Privacy & Security `>` Full Disk Access. Press `+`. You can't choose `cron` directly in the dialog, so press `CMD+SHIFT+G` and enter `/usr/sbin/` and then choose `cron`.